# HTML Scaling div when width is set in percents

Tags: css, html, width, scaling

So I need to have a `<div>` in the middle of the screen when the user first opens the website, I've tried to set width in percents and putting `<div>`inside `<center>` tag, but in both cases scaling doesn't work properly. How do I put a `<div>`in the center of the screen without problems with scaling?

By "scaling doesn't work" I mean when I zoom in too much it stops increasing width, while still increasing height and content, so it adds line-breaks and everything looks completely wrong

Thank you for responding, but your suggestions all have this problem I've described. The only way out so far is setting position to absolute and setting "top", "left", "width" and "height" parameters manually in cm. Take a look at the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="../../../All Files/HTML/Project/special.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class='centering'>
      <div class='content'>
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
      </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the css file:

```
.centering {
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#646464;
}
.content {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:50%;
    background-color:#2B2B2B;
}
```

I'm very grateful for spending your time helping me out!

Comment: What do you mean "scaling doesn't work". You should try and describe in more detail the behaviour that you are looking for. The best way to do that is provide code you have now, and point out what part is not working out

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HB3rB/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this:

```
<center>
    <div>
    </div>
</center>
```

Try this instead:

```
<div class="centering">
    <div class="content">
        Text here!
    </div>
</div>
```

and in your css:

```
.centering {
    text-align: center;
}
.content {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:50%;
}
```

Comment: It does not center div only. It centers div's content also.

Answer (score 1):

For example if your div is:

```
<div id="content">
  //div content
 </div>
```

then use in your css:

```
   #content {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

just change the width  as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this.

```
.wrapper{
      width:50%;
      margin:0 auto;
}

.content{
      float:left;
}

<div class='wrapper'>
      <div class='content'>
           //your content
      </div>
</div>
```

or for content selector you can also specify text-align property as left.